# holder.btn_email.setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

send an email with the email purchase data.

send when I click the button
btn_email

```
 //contability
            holder.btn_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openGmail(OrderStatus.this, new String[]{"leblabla@gmail.com"},"Contabilidade:App bla bla",
                            "bla bla bla bla bla bla"+Common.currentRequest.getName());
                    currentRequest=model;
                }
            });
```

I only get data that is "bla bla"

Comment: Can you show your `openGmail`  method?

Comment: What is `Common`?

Comment: private static void openGmail(Activity activity, String[] email, String subject, String content) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
        final PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        ResolveInfo best = null;

Comment: for(final ResolveInfo info : matches)
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail"))
                best = info;
        if (best != null)
            emailIntent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);

        activity.startActivity(emailIntent);
    }

Comment: What is Common? 

To set #public static Request currentRequest;#

Comment: I didn't get it, whats the actual problem, Gmail is opening correctly?

Comment: yes but dont guiv me the name of product

Comment: can u help me with metod thats can possible?